# Calculate aggregates on sql server or web server?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have these tables (some football tables)

1. Leagues: Id, Name
2. Teams: Id, Name, IdLeague
3. Stages: Id, Number, IdLeague
4. Matches: Id, IdStage, Date, IdTeam1, IdTeam2, Team1Score, Team2Score

My goal is to calculate the ranking of some league.

Position, TeamName, Wins, Draws, Defeats, GoalsScored, GoalsConceded, Points (3 * WIns + Draws).

If two teams have the same number of points there are more possibilites (team A and team B)

1. if there was a game team A vs team B but no game team B vs team A then the team with better goal difference (GoalsScored - GoalsConceded ) it's in advantage
2. if they played both games against each other in the league then the team with more points in that 2 games it's in advantage, if they grab equal number of points in those 2 games, then the team with with better goal difference in those 2 games it's in advantage
3. if that difference from 2) is the same, the team with more goals scored in these 2 direct matches it's in advantage
4. if 3) can't decide, the team with better goal difference in the league wins
5. if 4) can't decide, the team with more goals scored in the league wins
6. if 5) can't decide,..i don't know :)

Leagues table: there will be 3-4 rows
Teams table: there will be 60-80 rows (20 teams/ league) 
Stages table: there will be 114-152 rows (38 stages/league)
Matches tables: there will be 1149-1520 rows (10 matches/stage)

1. Is it better to make all aggregates for 1 league on sql server or just select all matches from that league and make all calculations on the server?
2. Can that ranking be calculated with 1 select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there are out of league games.

First if you have an odd number of teams or a rain out and not all team play the same number of games then Points is not apples to apples.

Why treat 1 different than 2?  Head to head then just say most wins as that is the same as points.  If there was a draw they both got the draw.

On 2. in league is superfluous as if it is a league ranking and they played each other then they are in the same league.

You could replace 1-3 with 1) head to head wins  2) head to head goals.

Where is what I would propose

```
0   total points
1   league points
2   head to head wins
3   head to head goals
4   league goals
5   total goals
```

I would put total goals last so an A team had little incentive to runs up goals on a C team.

I don't think that is one select as there are not the same number of rows.
Head to head will need to be a separate select.   Those are small tables.  You could do this with Access.

Head to head can be more complex if there is more than a 2 way tie.  You can assure the total number of games is equal by simply not ending a season unless total games is the same.  If you are going to make sure each team play another team the same number of times then the league size has to be 2 to a power (e.g. 16).   And you have to account for a possibility of a team pulling out or getting suspended.  It is almost impossible to assure symmetric schedules so need to have a ranking that tries to deal with it.   In a three way tie you could have two that split and a third that tied both.  In that situation the two the that split would have more wins 1 and but should not be ranked higher than the third with two ties.   So I would revise 2 with tie breaker point system of +1 win 0 tie -1 loss.  And to deal with possible other assymetries I would revise 3 to head to head goal differential sum.   And on those lines use sum goal differential for 4 and 5.

Comment: So, i create a stored procedure, get those aggregates (wins, defeats, draws, points) and in my application and use some looping there to calculate the ranking or just use rank() in sql server and some case based on those 5 situations?

Comment: It is just two queries.  You would use rank() for within a league.  If there is a tie in the first then look (with you eyes) to the second head to head.  I would not even try to automate that part.  There are not going to be a lot of ties and teams are going to want detail on the tie breaker.  And I revise my statement on head to head wins - see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your question is not on HOW to do all these calculations but on WHERE to do it, SQL Server or "The Server" (which by that I believe you mean, selecting the data and doing the calculation on your application, right?)

Assuming I understood correctly I can tell you that depends on how you are able to implement it. SQL Server is very good on doing aggregated calculations (group by with sum, etc..) but is not very good on looping (with cursors for example).

So, if you can build queries to get to your result, do it on SQL. If you need to do several operations like "for each row on a resultset, run other queries, update variables and so on (which would imply the use of cursors on SQL), its better to return the result sets to your application and do the looping there.